# Laravel 5 - Remove the less style sheets included in the template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I remove or disable the less files from getting loaded into my views. I am using custom stylesheets and the less styles which comes with the default laravel package (`resources\assets\less\bootstrap`) is affecting my custom styles.  I have found the `gulpfile.js` with the following code, but commenting the `mix.less` line doesn't disable the mixins from loading

```
    var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
    elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.less('app.less');
    });
```

Comment: Did you run `gulp` after commenting that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as Inurosen mentioned, you should run `gulp` after that in the root of your application on the command line.

I'm not sure which version of L5 you are running, but in some there is the command `php artisan fresh` . **Caution: this will remove all auth and bootstrap scaffolding.**